# Can't get desired effects of CSS Transition

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have prepared a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/JGFFd/25/

What I am aiming for is, when hovering on the coloured box, for the coloured box and avatar to animate to the left so that the coloured box grows in size and shows the text contained in the `inner` span.

It sounds simple like that but I can't seem to work it out so any help would be appreciated.

Here is a copy of the code that's in the fiddle:

```
<div class="blog-posts-grid-box">
    <div class="blog-posts-grid-box-content" id="grid-box0" data-id="id-0">                   
        <h3 class="grid-blog-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="blog-posts-grid-box-excerpt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do...</div>    
    </div> <!-- blog-posts-grid-box-content -->

    <div class="blog-posts-grid-box-pic">
        <img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/humano2/128x128/apps/comix.png" class="photo">
        <a href="#" target="_top">                      
            <span class="food">
                <span class="inner">Martin Carlin - Food</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- blog-posts-grid-box-pic -->
</div>




.blog-posts-grid-box {
    float: left;
    background-color: white;
    width: 218px;
    height: 223px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 24px;
    margin-right: 11px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-content {
    width: 195px;
    height: 145px;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-excerpt {
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 13px;
}

h3.grid-blog-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #24212A;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic {
    position: relative;
    bottom: -32px;
    right: -115px;
    -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s linear;
    -o-transition: width 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s linear;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, visibility 1s linear;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic img {
    width: 52px;
    height: 52px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic span.food {
    background-color: #FFA100;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic span {
    height: 52px;
    width: 52px;
    display: inline-block;
    background: url('/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/wpbook/team21/images/blog-grid-chevron.png') no-repeat 23px 21px;
    top: -42px;
    position: relative;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic .inner {
    display: inline-block;
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 0%;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic span:hover {
    width: 170px;
    visibility: visible;
    margin-left: -110px;
}

.blog-posts-grid-box-pic.inner span:hover {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

​
 ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little confused by what you are asking here. This is what I have cobbled together from your jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JGFFd/26/

I've switched the position of the `<img />` and `<a />` so that the avatar is affected by the `.food` transition. I've also replaced the css selectors using `span` in favour of using the class names. I think this is where you were getting the bulk of the issues.

Please just let me know if this is not what you were after and I'll take another swing!

:)

Comment: @Inrbob - thanks, that's great and exactly what I'm looking for! The only thing I can think to improve it would be to get the animation/transition smoother, something like in this, http://jsfiddle.net/9CRaX/1/ ?

Comment: okay gotcha! You're transitions were on the wrong element (at least in my version) so I've moved them. Also you can't transition `visibility`, it needs to be `opacity`. I've made the change. Bear in mind this will require rework for IE8 and 9 now: http://jsfiddle.net/JGFFd/29/

Comment: excellent, thank you. I'm just trying to work your magic into my code just now. Almost there, just a couple of issues I am trying to iron out.

Comment: Feel free to post as an update to your question; I'm happy to look closer

Comment: @Inrbob, thank - it's no issues to do with your answer, what is happening when I integrate it with my existing code is the avatar image disappears at the end of the transition for some reason, and then the only other thing I want to fix is on hover to either change the position of the chevron so that it stays where it was pre-transition, or hide the old background chevron and apply a new one. So far I've added a new background chevron but been unsuccessful on hiding the old one on hover.

Comment: fixed the image disappearing, just the chevron driving me mad now!

Comment: Cool - if you add that to your question (including what the chevron is) I'll look into it. I just don't want this list of comments to grow too long and I don't have enough time for to go to chat. EDIT: if the chevron is a background image, can't you just position it to the right? EDIT 2: use better image (appropriate whitespace) http://jsfiddle.net/JGFFd/32/

Comment: the chevron is in the fiddle but because it's locally hosted it didn't show, I think I have it, `.blog-posts-grid-box-pic span.food:hover {
    background-position: 131px 21px;
}` ? I am seeing two chevrons just now for some reason even though I took the new one out, not sure if it's cached in my browser (I have shift+rereshed a few times) because I don't see how there could be two of them now.